Cannot query even though using partition field in Google BigQuery
I have the following query:
select count(1)
from `some_catalogue.some_table_with_partitions`
WHERE date_trunc(period,week(MONDAY)) >= (select max(date_trunc(period,week(MONDAY))) from `some_catalogue.some_table_with_partitions` where period >= date_add(current_date('Asia/Jakarta'),interval -1 day) )

some_table_with_partitions is a table using period column as partition field. The error message that i get is:

Cannot query over table
'some_project.some_catalogue.some_table_with_partitions' without a
filter over column(s) 'period' that can be used for partition
elimination.

i thought i already hit the partition field as follows:
WHERE date_trunc(period,week(MONDAY)) >= (select max(date_trunc(period,week(MONDAY))) from `some_catalogue.some_table_with_partitions` where period >= date_add(current_date('Asia/Jakarta'),interval -1 day) )

how do i resolve this?

Hi @Cignitor, As per the documentation If a partitioned table has the Require partition filter setting, then every query on that table must include at least one predicate that only references the partitioning column. Queries without such a predicate return the error.  Refer to this link also and let me know your issue resolved or not?.

As "PUTHINEEDI RAMOJI RAO" wrote, the query needs to have a predicate filter on the partition row. This can be archived by adding a filter condition that prefilter on the dates. As the filter is looking on events happing yesterday and today and then it is truncted to the beginning of the week, going back 16 days should be enough.
With
conditonal_table as (
Select * from `some_catalogue.some_table_with_partitions` 
where period >= date_add(current_date('Asia/Jakarta'),interval -1 day) ))

select count(1)
from `some_catalogue.some_table_with_partitions`
WHERE date_trunc(period,week(MONDAY)) >= 
(select max(date_trunc(period,week(MONDAY))) from conditonal_table )
AND period>=current_date()-16 # does a prefiltering.

